# How can i remove extra space in mobile app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

[image]

I am using Highchart framework to develop a mobile app and I have made an app using Highchart, HTML and CSS. I've uploaded the screenshot from the app above.

I want to remove the space between the chart and the table.

Here is the code for the chart:

```
$(function () {
  $('#statement-graph').highcharts({
    chart: {
      plotBackgroundColor: null,
      plotBorderWidth: 0,
      plotShadow: true,
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      borderWidth: 0
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Expense',
      align: 'center',
      verticalAlign: 'middle',
      font: 'gothamrnd-light',
      y: -10,
      x : 1,
      style : {
        color: '#fff',
        fontSize: '0.9em'
      },
    },
    header :{

    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: 'Rs 25000',
      align: 'center',
      verticalAlign: 'middle',
      y: 10,
      x : 1,
      style : {
        color: '#fff',
        fontSize: '1.2em'
      },
    },
    exporting: { enabled: false },
    tooltip: {
      pointFormat: '<b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          format: '<b>{point.name}</b>',
          style: {
            color: 'white',
            textShadow: '0px 0px 0px white',
            fontWeight: '200',
            font: '13px gothamrnd-light'
          },
          connectorColor: 'white',
        }
      },
      pie: {
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false
        },
        shadow: true,
        center: ['50%', '50%'],
        borderWidth: 0 // < set this option
      }
    },

    series: [{
      type: 'pie',
      name: '',
      innerSize: '50%',
      showInLegend: false,
      data: [
        {
          name: 'Utilities',
          y: 45, 
          color : "#D2C993"
        },
        {
          name: 'Clothing',
          y: 30,
          color : "#CD7D80"
        },
        {
          name: 'Entertainment',
          y: 15,
          color : "#B486B1"
        },
        {
          name: 'Medical',
          y: 12,
          color : "#5CB1CE"
        },
        {
          name: 'Vacations',
          y: 23,
          color : "#F2C56A"
        },
        {
          name: 'Food & Drinks',
          y: 30,
          color : "#F78E58"
        }
      ]
    }]
  });
});
```

Here is the HTML for the Highchart:

```
<div id="statement-graph" style="
    height: 60vh;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    display: table;"></div>
```

Comment: You mean reducing the space between the chart and the table, the one coloured?

Comment: The thing to note here is, you don't set the the size of the pie. Therefore Highcharts changes the chart size to fit all the labels in the plot area. If you try reducing the connector length and shorten the labels, you'd see that the chart is bigger and the space is reduced. If you always know the length of the longest label then you can try and see which pie size is the best and then according to that manipulate the container size to reduce the space between the table and the chart

Comment: @FedericoMartinez yes.

Comment: @RahulSharma ok. I will try that.

Comment: Adjust the margin of the highchart with negative values for bottom and top. Something like margin: -10px auto. Just take into account what Rahul said and adjust accordingly.

Comment: @FedericoMartinez I did that. It's still not working

Comment: I think that you should be able to reduce this gap using chart.marginBottom parameter, as well as plotOptions.pie.size (and maybe pie.center). I have made simple example showing how it can work with an example form Highcharts site: http://jsfiddle.net/mnua1rue/ As you can see, the gap between pie and bottom of the container is reduced.

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński ok. i will try that.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to see the resulting page source code, so I could identify the elements' separate ID's or classes, but here's one suggestion.  In your code for the chart you have:

```
  pie: {
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: false
    },
    shadow: true,
    center: ['50%', '50%'],
    borderWidth: 0 // < set this option
  }
```

Try changing

center: ['50%', '50%'], to

center: ['50%', '25%'], or

center: ['50%', '75%'],

...and where you have:

```
subtitle: {
  text: 'Rs 25000',
  align: 'center',
  verticalAlign: 'middle',
  y: 10,
  x : 1,
  style : {
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: '1.2em'
  },
},
```

You could try changing

```
  verticalAlign: 'middle',
```

to verticalAlign: 'bottom',